# Obtaining Taylor series coefficients in numerically stable way?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

From a circuit simulator, I get a nonlinear $y=f(x)$ relationship as data points. The relationship looks linear at the first glance but it is a circuit that is considered very nonlinear.

My goal is to model this relationship with a Taylor series expansion $\hat{y} = c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^3$

I obtain the coefficients with numerical differentiation (e.g. `diff` in MATLAB) from the datapoints. These are the plots of the derivative for a stepsize of $10\mu V$ (not something extraordinarily small) resulting in 20001 datapoints:

[image]

Note that the third derivative is very noise and nearly useless.

Now if change the stepsize to 10mV (only 201 datapoints) I get:

[image]

This is much less noisy and makes more sense.

However, I want to get the highest accuracy so I would assume the smaller my stepsize the better the results. The opposite is counter intuitive to me. How would I even select the step size?

Is this nonlinear modeling with Taylor series known to be so impractical? (as said, this is not considered a highly linear circuit!)

If not, is there a better way to obtain the derivatives?

Comment: it is unclear what you want. $f'''$ is noisy except at the origin, isn't it what you desired, a Taylor expansion around $x= 0$ ? And as MGirard said, the signal becomes more and more noisy as you differentiate it, this is because $diff$ is a high-pass filter, and usually the noise is high frequency while the wanted signal is in the low-frequencies. You can't do anything to overcome that, except that your 3rd Taylor coefficient is insignificant for $|x|\ll1$, and it becomes very significant for $|x|\gg1$ : for estimating the larger Taylor coefs you need to know the signal at the larger $x$

Comment: You might want to look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials on $[-1,1]$ that are quite similar to the Fourier series decomposition, and lead to a robust decomposition as a sum of polynomials (robust because the noise keeps the same energy after the decomposition) but they give more weight to the small powers of $x$, since $\int_{-1}^1 |x^n|^2 dx$ becomes very small as $n$ increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your noise comes from your circuit solver. Circuit solvers typically solve the equations down to some precision , typically $10^{-6}$ relative (only linear systems have exact values down to floating point precision).

If your stepsize is very small, $f(x+\varepsilon) - f(x)$ is also small (on the order of $\varepsilon f'(x)$). Every time you call the `diff` function, you perform a substraction of two data points. Assuming an absolute uncertainty of $\delta$, after N calls to `diff`, your absolute uncertainty is of $N^2 \delta$. To get derivatives, you need to divide by $\varepsilon$, which raises the absolute uncertainty to $N^2 \delta \varepsilon^{-N}$ while the numerical scheme error is on the order of $O(\varepsilon)$. This error can become much larger than the numerical scheme error so raising the stepsize $\varepsilon$ will reduce the overall error.

Raising the circuit solver tolerance could alleviate the issue. Otherwise, I would suggest fitting your data to your proposed equation.

Comment: Does $\delta$ correspond to reltol or abstol (vabstol, iabstol)? I thought about this but changing tolerances does not seem to change significantly. For example, reltol=vabstol=iabstol=1e-12, then stepsize $\epsilon = (1/(N^2 \delta))^(-1/(N+1))=1.7mV$. Result is not noisy. But then I reduce the tolerances to 1e-3 (keeping stepsize at 1.7mV) but the third derivative is still not (very) noisy. Do I misinterpret your equations?

Comment: The fitting suggestion is a good idea! Unfortunately the results are not consistent at all with the circuit simulator (which are off by 10dB or a factor of 15!).

Comment: The $\delta$ in my answer was absolute tolerance (they were additive on substraction). Basically, you want to keep $N^2 \delta \varepsilon^{-N}$ under the value of the derivative you're trying to sample. Your overall error on values goes as $O(\varepsilon) + O(\varepsilon^{-N})$, so your stepsize cannot be either too small or too large. Out of curiosity, are you using a SPICE model ?